# My neural net plots stop working when I add 20 and 50 neurons in the hidden layer, does anyone know what the problem is?

Tags: neural-network, r, plotting

I just have four basic neural net plots, each one has a different number of neurons in the hidden layer. The first has 3 neurons, the second 10, the third 20, and the fourth 50. The issue is the plots work up until there's 20 neurons in the hidden layer, but then it stalls for a while and starts to break down, with messier looking plots, and I get this error: `> plot20 <- plot(nn20, rep="best") Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) :  non-finite location and/or size for viewport`

Here's the [cancer data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRPfNXLn8QmFQonm33DCkg3DjrqHJzEaXT_R0CpTNWw/edit?usp=sharing) in a public google spreadsheet and the code, this excludes all of the models because they're the same thing but with different numbers of neurons:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(neuralnet)
library(ISLR) 
library(caTools)
library(random)
library(cowplot)

setwd("**insert path**")
data <- read.csv("WDBC.csv", header=T)
#head(data)

#Select the important variables
cancerdata <- subset(data, select = c(Diagnosis, texture, smoothness, area))
head(cancerdata) 

train <- sample(x = nrow(cancerdata), size = nrow(cancerdata)*0.5)

cancertrain <- cancerdata[train,]
cancervalid <- cancerdata[-train,]
print(nrow(cancertrain))
print(nrow(cancervalid))

nn20 <- neuralnet(Diagnosis ~ area+texture+smoothness, data=cancertrain, hidden=numHneurons20,  
                rep = 2, err.fct = "ce", linear.output = F, lifesign = "minimal", stepmax = 10000000)

plot20 <- plot(nn20, rep="best")
```

Here are the plots, the ones with 3 and 10 neurons in the hidden layer work but it breaks on 20 neurons and never gets to 50. I'm wondering if there's a technique to deal with larger numbers of neurons to be less messy and if I need to do something to keep it simplified?

**hidden neurons = 3**

[image]

**hidden neurons = 10**

[image]

**hidden neurons = 20**

[image]

Comment: I suspect some plotting parameter needs tuning to show the plots correctly

Comment: @NikosM. yeah that's the problem